# Trying to use a 7 segment display to count 0/9 with a potentiometer

Tags: arduino-uno

im trying to switch number on the display using a 
    potentiometer, it is just counting from 0/9.
    All help is much appreciated!

```
int SegmentA = 6;
int SegmentB = 7;
int SegmentC = 8;
int SegmentD = 9;
int SegmentE = 10;
int SegmentF = 11;
int SegmentG = 12;


const int PP = A0;


void setup()
{
  pinMode (SegmentA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (SegmentB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (SegmentC, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (SegmentD, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (SegmentE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (SegmentF, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (SegmentG, OUTPUT);


}

void loop() {

  int POD = analogRead(PP);
  int SM = map(POD, 0, 1023, 0 , 8);
  switch (SM) {


    case 0:
      digitalWrite (SegmentA, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentB, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentC, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentD, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentE, HIGH);   //0
      digitalWrite (SegmentF, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentG, LOW);

      delay(1000);

    case 1:
      digitalWrite (SegmentA, LOW);
      digitalWrite (SegmentB, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentC, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentD, LOW);
      digitalWrite (SegmentE, LOW);   //1
      digitalWrite (SegmentF, LOW);
      digitalWrite (SegmentG, LOW);

      delay(1000);

    case 2:
      digitalWrite (SegmentA, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentB, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentC, LOW);
      digitalWrite (SegmentD, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentE, HIGH);   //2
      digitalWrite (SegmentF, LOW);
      digitalWrite (SegmentG, HIGH);

      delay(1000);

    case 3:
      digitalWrite (SegmentA, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentB, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentC, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentD, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentE, LOW);   //3
      digitalWrite (SegmentF, LOW);
      digitalWrite (SegmentG, HIGH);

      delay(1000);

    case 4:
      digitalWrite (SegmentA, LOW);
      digitalWrite (SegmentB, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentC, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentD, LOW);
      digitalWrite (SegmentE, LOW);   //4
      digitalWrite (SegmentF, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentG, HIGH);

      delay(1000);

    case 5:
      digitalWrite (SegmentA, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentB, LOW);
      digitalWrite (SegmentC, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentD, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentE, LOW);   //5
      digitalWrite (SegmentF, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentG, HIGH);

      delay(1000);

    case 6:
      digitalWrite (SegmentA, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentB, LOW);
      digitalWrite (SegmentC, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentD, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentE, HIGH);   //6
      digitalWrite (SegmentF, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentG, HIGH);

      delay(1000);

    case 7:
      digitalWrite (SegmentA, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentB, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentC, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentD, LOW);
      digitalWrite (SegmentE, LOW);   //7
      digitalWrite (SegmentF, LOW);
      digitalWrite (SegmentG, LOW);

      delay(1000);

    case 8:
      digitalWrite (SegmentA, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentB, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentC, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentD, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentE, HIGH);   //8
      digitalWrite (SegmentF, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (SegmentG, HIGH);

  }

}
```

Comment: I would shorten the delay (1000) to be much less - otherwise you turn the pot, nothing happens, you turn it some and finally something happens but now you've overshot what you wanted, and you overdo it the other way trying to get to where you wanted.  Try a delay of 50 to 100, have it be much more reactive to turning the knob.  You can then move on to using a rotary decoder with detents, one click for one number change.  Here's a poorly lit example with 2 digits and rotary encoder.  In this case, a shift register was used to drive each display (vs multiplexing).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f51eSlcZt-g  The link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You miss the break statement at the end of each case. e.g.:

```
  digitalWrite (SegmentF, LOW);
  digitalWrite (SegmentG, HIGH);

  delay(1000);

  break;

case 4:
```

This causes each case to perform, and continue with the next case. However, since there is a delay of 1 second, it looks like it is counting.

Actually, I would expect it counts from a certain value depending on the pot meter to 7, since there is no digit 9 implemented, and the delay for the 8 digit is missing too.

To further improve your code, you can add the delay not in every case but at the end, since I assume there always will be one digit selected.

Also you can make a function void showDigit with a parameter for each of the possible segment states and replace all (almost) duplicated code by that function call, or send the digit and use showDigit to set internally the states of each segment (by using a boolean array[nr_of_digits][nr_of_segments], somewhat like Nic Hartley proposes below.

Comment: I would add that you don't even need that `switch` -- you can easily have a `const bool digits[7 * 10]`, then pass `digits[7 * digit]`, and in the function pull from `param[0]`, `param[1]`, etc.

Comment: @NicHartley Thanks ... I think a two dimensional array is than even better, but the use of an array is better in general.

Comment: @Michel Keijzers I couldn't remember the syntax for a 2D array off the top of my head so I just went with 1D, but you're correct -- either would work. 2D would probably be prettier.

Comment: Actually, strictly speaking, you could also do a `const uint8_t digits[10];`, then access the individual segments with `digits[n] & (1 << segment)`, if you wanted it to be the _least_ readable possible code. I wouldn't recommend that over the array (probably 2D array) approach, though, unless you have some _extremely_ tight memory requirements.

Comment: @NicHartley since the Arduino has only 2 KB this might be useful, but indeed, only when needed. I always prefer readability over memory reduction.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers I suggested it only for the very rare circumstances where you find yourself exhausting all 2KB and need to compact things down even more. It's _definitely_ not a good thing to start with, I agree.

Comment: @NicHartley I run out immediately with 2 KB (that's why I want to do my 'main' project with an STM which has 192 KB (but maybe I should have used a Raspberry).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Huh. I've never had an issue with it. I "grew up" in very tightly constrained environments, though, so maybe I have a different style. Anyway, this has all gotten somewhat off-topic, haha.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85768/discussion-between-michel-keijzers-and-nic-hartley).

Answer (score 3):

You'll want a single delay (if any) at the bottom of the loop() function. You may not need it since it will keep displaying the current digit until you move the potentiometer. Exception: if the pot is near the edge between 2 digits, you could see some dithering.

Replace the delay-calls in the `case`s with `break;` statements. Otherwise whichever case you call will fall through into the case below it, and so on, displaying subsequent each digit in turn, which isn't what you wanted (and is what you are already seeing).

Change the map() call to `map(POD, 0, 1024, 0 , 10)`. Otherwise there will be no '9' band on potentiometer and the '8' band will be only 1 value wide (out of 1023): exactly the value "1023". You'd like the '9' band to be about as wide as all of the others. It's even possible that a given potentiometer won't get close enough to zero resistance for you to get a 1023 reading.